# Add more properties to a union of objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to add an additional property to an union of objects that I already have in a type.

The type that I have is something like this:

```
type A = {
    something: {a: 1} | {b: 1} | {c: 1};
    somethingElse: 2;
}
```

And would like to transform it into something like this:

```
type A = {
    something: {a: 1, newProp: 1} | {b: 1, newProp: 1} | {c: 1, newProp: 1};
    somethingElse: 2;
}
```

That's, adding `newProp` to the objects in the union inside `something`.

I believe I could write a utility helper, something like this:

```
type WithNewProp<T> = T extends A ? T /* not sure what to do here */ : T

type B = WithNewProp<A>
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally, intersecting a union with another type works:

```
type B = {
    something: A["something"] & { newProp: 1 };
    somethingElse: 2;
};

declare const x: B["something"];

if ("a" in x) {
    x // { a: 1, newProp: 1 }
}
```

If you really want to distribute the intersection among all members, you could write a utility type:

```
type DistributeIntersection<U, T> = U extends U ? U & T : never;

type B = {
    something: DistributeIntersection<A["something"], { newProp: 1 }>;
    somethingElse: 2;
};

type X = B["something"];
/*
 ({
    a: 1;
} & {
    newProp: 1;
}) | ({
    b: 1;
} & {
    newProp: 1;
}) | ({
    c: 1;
} & {
    newProp: 1;
})
*/
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFTUDOB7AthMABYCWAdgOYBcyAhrQIwC+UAPsgEZOsdIDGPANzosOAkTJUAogBtsEWgCYRaZqvShIUACKlswAE6lOAV2AQAkuQuGF-YKVzkAPAFUANFAAqAPgRQblAQAB4W5AAm2IFQAPwxAGQ+ULTkEABuEIYaaFrQAEIBqBhYeIQkFDS6+kYm5lY2WfaOzi4wANoARGWSlZ0Aul5IUGkA7gAKhrhgTFDMvqpiPRUy8opQKujq6Jrg0AAaAfldy1KUA+hAA)

Comment: This is very clear and works like a charm, thanks. I have a follow up question you might be able to solve, it elaborates on this but gets a bit tricker (for myself). Appreciate if you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76184399/2002514