# Add property to nested property in union of objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I got a great answer from a previous question to add a property to the objects inside a union: [Add more properties to a union of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76183408/add-more-properties-to-a-union-of-objects).

Now I've been trying to extend that solution into a nested object inside the union:

```
type A = {
    something: {a: 1, nestedA: {
      a: 1,
      // add `newProp: 1` here
    }} | {b: 1, nestedB: {
      b: 1
      // add `newProp: 1` here
    }} | {c: 1},
    somethingElse: 2
};
```

We can be certain about the nested level of the object where `newProp` should be added, meaning that is always one level deep of the objects in the union, but we will manually have to tell it the keys where we want to add the prop as there is no way to tell beforhand:

```
type SomeCrazyHelper<T, 'nestedA' | 'nestedB'>
```

and after the TypeScript wizardry it should become:

```
type B = {
    something: {a: 1, nestedA: {
      a: 1,
      newProp: 1
    }} | {b: 1, nestedB: {
      b: 1,
      newProp: 1
    }} | {c: 1},
    somethingElse: 2
};
```

but it gets really confusing for me how to apply a distributed intersection in this more complex case.

Appreciate any ideas on this.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFTUDOB7AthMABYCWAdgOYBcyAhrQIwA0U5E2wEAJjLahiyYGUFuiGYA9JKh1u3KAAN2AdwAKAJ1xgmiqMQgaI4rAF9TUAD7IARk1btOPAEL8TQu6PdZps+UtVNbV19Q2NBTHMrZABjJlNmbzxCEgpKAFEAG2wIWgAmdFMAbnR0UEgoABFSTg1SGwBXLgBJci4NHJjgUlxyAB4AVVYAFQA+BCgBqAgADy5ybmxJqAB+ZYAyKGGoWnYAN0MStDLwaGcJgSFkojIqWhgAbQBya9SqJ4BdQqOTioANCbOB4AIlet0owK+aCAA)

Comment: How should we determine where exactly `newProp:1` should be added?

Comment: You are right, that's not clear, thanks for asking! Updated the question @wonderflame, please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wj0A8m) work for you? If yes, I will write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: We also can check even deeper, like in [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wezRaN). Which one do you prefer?

Comment: Beautiful! thanks @wonderflame. The first approach does it but doesn't hurt to add the second option to the answer as it might be valuable also as reference for someone else and still covers the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The utility type we will use will need several generic parameters: the type that we want to modify, the properties that we want to alter, and what we want to add to properties.

Since we know that the first level is not where we want to look for the keys, we will have a wrapper around the core utility type:

```
type SomeCrazyHelper<Obj, Keys extends string, Extra> = {
  [K in keyof Obj]: Prettify<_SomeCrazyHelper<Obj[K], Keys, Extra>>;
};
```

This type will call `_SomeCrazyHelper` for every property in the `Obj`, where we will look for the properties to alter.
In `_SomeCrazyHelper` we will map through the keys and check if the key is in the `Keys` then we are altering it and stop recursion, if not we are calling `_SomeCrazyHelper` recursively to check the deeper layers:

```
type _SomeCrazyHelper<Obj, Keys extends string, Extra> = {
  [K in keyof Obj]: Prettify<
    K extends Keys ? Obj[K] & Extra : _SomeCrazyHelper<Obj[K], Keys, Extra>
  >;
};
```

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
      [K in keyof R]: R[K];
    }
  : never;
```

`Prettify` is the utility that allows to remove `&` from the type, for example if we pass `{a: string} & {b: string}` to `Prettify`, it will return more readable version of the code:

```
{
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

Usage:

```
type Result = SomeCrazyHelper<A, 'veryDeep' | 'veryDeep2', { newProp: 1 }>;
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wezRaN)